# Creating a UWP project in Visual Studio 2015 results in a ".NETCore 5.0 missing" message

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I installed Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (version 14.0.23104.0 D14REL) with tools for building Universal Windows Apps. Every time I create or load a Windows Universal project (unit test, class library), I get the following error:

[image: Update required .NETCore 5.0 missing]

The download link unhelpfully goes to microsoft.com and I can't find a "framework SDK" download for .NET Core anywhere.

I tried installing the CoreCLR runtime using the DNX tool, but that didn't change anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried to also install the SDK? https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: Right. I installed the 10.0.26624 Windows 10 SDK and no dice - the message is still the same.

Comment: reinstall th VStools: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=619629

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and run the [Windows 10 VS Tools Installer for Vs2015 Enterprise](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=619629) and select the Windows 10 Development tools. This reinstalls everything relates to Windows 10 development.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I noticed that the v5.0 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore" was missing. This issue only arose after I installed the vs2017 and uninstalled it (meaning it removed the v5.0 folder during the uninstall process). I tried everything from repairing to uninstalling/reinstalling vs2015 but none recreated that folder.

Here is my v5.0 zip try placing it in the above mentioned path (never tried it myself, i just reinstalled vs2017)
[https://www.mediafire.com/?hmdt5k41kvsyqt6](http://v5.0)

Comment: I have the same problem after I uninstalled vs2017RC. Your solution should work but your v5.0 zip seems to be broken, it should not be as small as 64k in size.

Comment: hey, I uploaded my latest v5.0 folder not sure if it will work and it looks the same to me.. good luck !! https://www.mediafire.com/folder/crgvc2srfzr7l/Visual_Studio_2015_v5.0